# Ionic serve throws this error code help please

Tags: ionic-framework, application-icon

Ionic serve throughs the error below when I run it.
When I change color of tabs with default settings like from stable ---> to positive it works and makes the changes but when i try to override it with my custom color nothing change for example if i try to make positive variable red nothing changes.

any one can  help ?

```
 stream.js:94
     throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: EACCES, open '/Users/cabdifitaaraden/Desktop/Lasoco/www/css/ionic.app.css
```

Comment: please provide relevant code

Comment: its fresh out of the box I have not made any changes. ionic start myApp tabs and then ionic setup sass and then i have done ionic serve thats when i get this error

Comment: I also have same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error as well when running the `ionic serve` command.

I think it's just a permissions thing as using sudo solved it for me `sudo ionic serve`.

Comment: Yes i have figured that out last night after long trail and error

Answer (score 1):

Did you run Sass setup with sudo rights? (`sudo ionic setup sass`)

If so, the files that were generated by Sass are not accessible with standard user rights due to a permission issue.

You have two options:

a) run ionic serve with sudo rights: **`sudo ionic serve`**

b) fix the problem by changing the owner of the following files:

- www/css/ionic.app.css
- www/css/ionic.app.min.css

You can do this with the chown command. Here's a one-liner that does the job (just adjust *yourUser* to your user account name):

- **`sudo chown -Rv yourUser www/css`**